# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: firebase, mobile, ionic3

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com Ionic 3 e Firebase, onde tem o crud.
O meu problema é que estou tentando salvar os dados, porém na hora de salvar ele apresenta que não tenho permissão. O que eu devo fazer?

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: PERMISSION_DENIED:
>   Permission denied Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
>       at Repo.js:510
>       at Object.exports.exceptionGuard (util.js:536)
>       at Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (Repo.js:501)
>       at Repo.js:278
>       at PersistentConnection.js:402
>       at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.js:435)
>       at Connection.onDataMessage_ (Connection.js:262)
>       at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.js:256)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (Connection.js:157)
>       at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.js:197)
>       at Repo.js:510

Comment: Verifique as suas regras de segurança da realtime database, na consola do Firebase

Comment: Encontrei, obrigada!

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, salvou minha vida.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme o Rosário disse... Para dar permissões nas regras de segurança da realtime database, no console do Firebase:

Primeiro, entrei em:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/
```

feito isso, entrar no projeto correspondente.

Em seguida, clicar em Database que fica na barra lateral, depois clicar em primeiros passos, onde será possível fazer a alteração para true (permissão). Por fim, atualizar o app e pronto.

Comment: Permita-me lembrar-lhe que colocando tudo em true deixará a sua database pública, o que significa que qualquer pessoa pode ler e escrever dados nela. Recomendo [este artigo](https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/como-funcionam-as-regras-de-seguran%C3%A7a-do-firebase-na-realtime-database-45b28cda14ad) se quiser estruturar as suas regras de forma segura.